# Generating a unique ID from a SQL subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to insert the result of a subquery into a table, but the table I want to insert into has a unique primary ID. I want to take the max of the EID number and add 1 to any entry I'm trying to insert to the table.

**Table I want to Insert Into:**

```
----------------------------------------------------
EID (pk)     |     First Name       | Employment Date
----------------------------------------------------
   1         |     John             |      2016-01-01
   2         |     Joe              |      2013-01-01
   3         |     Jill             |      2012-01-01
   4         |     Jen              |      2017-01-01
```

My subquery statement:

```
(SELECT FIRSTNAME, ORDERDATE as EMPLOYMENTDATE
  FROM CUSTOMER, ORDER
WHERE CUSTOMER.id = ORDER.id
AND ORDERDATE >= DATE '2017-01-01')
```

The problem is inserting, as I don't have an unique ID to generate. This is on SQL Server

I am trying to insert something like this:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EID, FIRSTNAME, EMPLOYMENTDATE)
SELECT ??????WHAT GOES HERE??????, FIRSTNAME, ORDERDATE as EMPLOYMENTDATE
  FROM CUSTOMER, ORDER
WHERE CUSTOMER.id = ORDER.id
AND ORDERDATE >= DATE '2017-01-01'
```

Comment: Mysql or sql server? Please add only the relevant tags

Comment: what's your full query look like?

Comment: If EID is auto_increment (MySQL), and insert SQL does not contains EID column, it will work

Comment: The table structure you shared has column `EmployeeEmail` but the select does not have that. Is this intentional or are you missing something here?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya That was not intentional, fixed it to make more sense

Answer (score 0):

Assuming EID is identity, this is how:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(FIRSTNAME, EMPLOYMENTDATE)
SELECT  FIRSTNAME, ORDERDATE as EMPLOYMENTDATE
  FROM CUSTOMER, ORDER
WHERE CUSTOMER.id = ORDER.id
AND ORDERDATE >= DATE '2017-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, since you're using a subquery it would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EID, FIRSTNAME, EMPLOYMENTDATE)
SELECT 
    ISNULL((MAX(Emp.EID)+1),1) AS EID,
    CustOrd.FirstName,
    CustOrd.EmploymentDate
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE Emp,
    (SELECT FIRSTNAME, ORDERDATE as EMPLOYMENTDATE
     FROM CUSTOMER, ORDER
     WHERE CUSTOMER.id = ORDER.id
     AND ORDERDATE >= DATE '2017-01-01') CustOrd
```

Comment: This is assuming EID is not an Identity column.

Comment: I get this error code ""EID" is not valid in the context where it is used."

Comment: Hi JasonDor, please see the change I made to the code above.